# JPA: how are null values sorted?

Tags: java, jpa

Lets assume a simple JPA query like:

```
from MyObject where foo = ? order by bar desc
```

Lets also assume that bar is a basic attribute, like a string or integer. Finally, bar is nullable. Where do the MyObjects with bar == null appear in the list - at the top or at the bottom? Is this provider- and/or db-specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database specific. Some JPA vendors (e.g DataNucleus JPA) provide an extension to specify

```
NULLS FIRST | LAST
```

on each order by clause

Comment: All databases that support the concept ;-) See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/jpql.html#ordering   We all know that very little SQL is truly portable no matter what "standard" they put it in since RDBMS vendors support what they feel like

Comment: I accept this one for giving an answer AND a possible workaround. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer to this in the EJB spec:

> SQL rules for the ordering of null values apply: that is, all null values must appear before all non-null
>   values in the ordering or all null values must appear after all non-null values in the ordering, but it is not
>   speciﬁed which.

So basically you have to do the ordering manually in this case as you cannot be sure in which position the null values will be returned by the database.

Answer (score 1):

That is DB specific and it is not covered by the JPA spec as far as I know.

Example: Just imagine that you fetch 10 out of 10 mlns sorted values from DB, and then want to decide in your code to sort them another way: not an easy task => this is database's task.

Comment: I agree. I our case we talk on 2-5 entries and using order by would have helped in sorting things out but we can do it manually after doing a pre-filtering with the db. Not pretty, but works on every db.

Comment: I can't find "ISNULL" in the JPA (2.1) spec. You could put "FUNCTION" in there with ISNULL as the function name, assuming the RDBMS supports it.

Comment: `IS NULL` is defined, but that can be used only in the `WHERE` part, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the SQL implementation, but my experience is NULL sorts as if it were the empty string.   In other words before everything else.